# Convert between text and varchar(MAX) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have read only access to some SQL Sever 2008 R2 database and I need to copy data from some of its tables to the tables in my database; both databases have the same collation.

The source database uses a lot of columns of `text` datatype. Can I safely make the target columns in my database of type `varchar(MAX)` and copy data without any risk (I am using INSERT statements to copy data)?

In other words, can I safely copy string data from column of `text` type to the column of `varchar(MAX)`? Both columns use the same collation.

Comment: Note: after warning us for years - MS have actually removed TEXT type for `Sql Data Warehouse` in the cloud. It is still available for `Azure SQL Database` but the super-high-end data warehousing has removed it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-data-types

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Yes, definitely - `VARCHAR(MAX)` is the type you should be using anyway.  The underlying implementation of both types is essentially the same (on large enough data, or after a type change from text to `VARCHAR(MAX)`), if you worry about that.

You can even "convert" an existing column of type `TEXT` to `VARCHAR(MAX)` by means of:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTableHere
ALTER COLUMN YourTextColumnHere VARCHAR(MAX)
```

This will turn your `TEXT` column into a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column without any data loss.

Try it! (*on a **copy** of your existing database first, of course*)

Comment: is it really safe to do that. What happens if `text` column is larger then the `varchar(max)` column. Would'nt you cut the text then?

Comment: Yes, it is safe.  `NVARCHAR(max)` is not `NVARCHAR(4000)`.  There is no length limit with `NVARCHAR(max)`.

Comment: Ok. So a simple test. Like this: `DECLARE @text VARCHAR(MAX);SET @text=REPLICATE('0,',200000);SELECT DATALENGTH(@text);`. Can you explain why DATALENGTH return 8000?

Comment: @JirkaHanika: *no length limit* is a bit too optimistic - at 2 GB (or 1 billion Unicode characters), there **will** be a limit. But that's good enough for several hundred copies of Leo Tolstoj's *War and Peace* - in a single column :-)

Comment: @Arion: add a line `SET @Text = @Text + @Text + @Text` and you get 24'000 characters.... it's a limitation of SQL Server **Management Studio** - not of SQL Server itself.

Comment: @marc_s : ok fine. Just asking so that this is the best solution. +1

Comment: @marc_s - You are right, I wrote this with this particular task in mind.  So to conclude: `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is `NVARCHAR(1000000000)` with a performance optimization for data that would happen to fit in `NVARCHAR(4000)`: such short data is stored in-line (in `NVARCHAR` fashion), whereas larger data is stored as blobs, in `NTEXT` like fashion.

Comment: @Arion - The `REPLICATE` effect is caused by the type of your '0,' string (backward compatible behavior).  The following will generate huge data just fine: `REPLICATE(CAST('0,' as NVARCHAR(MAX)), 200000))`.  SSMS is not involved here.

Comment: I've still yet to figure out why in the world SQL Management Studio feels the need to drop and recreate a table when changing column data types. I had hoped by now the script generation would have become more intelligent.

Comment: Would converting TEXT datetype columns to Varchar(max) save me some space? I have a 40GB table that has 3 Text Columns for notes and some other data that is stuffed in there with 10M records. thanks

Comment: @SQLnbe: no - it's still the same, variable-length, 1 byte per character text - it's not compressed or otherwise "optimized" .

Comment: A full text catalog (FULLTEXT INDEX) on the column in question will stop the change to varchar. Luckily I didn't need mine any more!